# suitable benchmark to use for Sharpe ratio of power trading strategy

Tags: sharpe-ratio, commodities

I have a algo which is trading a certain power contract. For calculating the Sharpe ration what would be a suitable benchmark to use?

Comment: This depends on your strategy. Can you give us more information about it? Do you want to rank the strategy against other similar strategies? Does your payoff have fat tails or is it skewed?

Comment: it's a simple intraday strategy trading a particular energy forward

Comment: Sorry, just making sure I understand the question: Are you looking for an alternative to the Sharpe Ratio, or are you looking for a Sharpe ratio benchmark value against which you can compare your algo results?